# Run different stages/pipelines for different azure devops triggers

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've recently started working with azure pipelines (experience with GitHub actions). I am trying to run stages based with different triggers, for example:

- For all pushes to my repo I want to run my linter
- For all PRs I want to run my tests
- For all merges to master I want to run my deployment pipeline

From what I read from the documentation of azure pipelines, this isn’t possible. If I understand correctly, I can only define 1 trigger value on the top of my azure-pipelines.yml value. Is this really true? Or am I overseeing something? Within github actions I know this can be solved be creating different workflows (lint-workflow, test-workflow etc) with each a separate trigger).

Comment: You can use conditions to control which jobs run when the pipeline is triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Azure DevOps, the Trigger field is used to trigger the whole pipeline. So you can only define 1 trigger value on the top of yaml file. Refer to this doc: [Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops)

Based on your requirement, you need to control the running of the stages.

I suggest that you can add Conditions in each of your stages. Refer to this doc about [Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

Here is an sample:

```
trigger:
- '*'

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

stages:
  - stage: linter_stage
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')
    jobs:
      - job: A
        steps:
          xxx

  - stage: test_stage
    condition: eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest')
    jobs:
      - job: B
        steps:
          xxx
  - stage: deployment_stage
    condition:  and(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main'))
    jobs:
      - job: C
        steps:
          xxx
```

**Explanation：**

1. At the top of the YAML you need to define Trigger as `*` to make sure any changes will trigger the pipeline.
2. You can use the `build.reason` and `Build.SourceBranch` variable  to determine if stages need to be run

Here is the doc about the [predefined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

**Result:**

[image]